# c# MRZ TDI1 Check Digit doesn't match with check digit number

Tags: c#

I have one dll application. In this application I am extacting some values.There in information about extraction.
.[image]

and I wrote c# code from this [link](https://www.doubango.org/SDKs/mrz/docs/Data_validation.html) guide to calculate digit number. and I will compare it. Below code  I wrote for c# to calculate

```
        private static int[] _weights = { 7, 3, 1 };
        private static SortedDictionary<char, int> GetMappedDictionary()
        {
            string charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            SortedDictionary<char, int> mappedValues = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
            char[] charArr = charset.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; ++i)
            {
                mappedValues[charArr[i]] = i;
            }
            mappedValues['<'] = 0;
            return mappedValues;        
        }
        private static int MrzComputeWeight(string line, int start, int end)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            SortedDictionary<char, int> mappedValues = GetMappedDictionary();
            for (int i = start, j = 0; i <= end; ++i, ++j)
            {
                var a = mappedValues[(line)[i]];
                var b = _weights[j % 3];
                sum += a *b; 
            }
            return sum;
        }
        private static bool MrzCheckValidty(string line, int start, int end,int indexDigit)
        {
            int weight = MrzComputeWeight(line, start, end);
            return (weight % 10) == Int32.Parse(line.Substring(indexDigit, 1));            
        }
```

Now It works for all test examples but It doesn't work for

> IDUTOBE01124128TEST1234V<<<<<<

here document id is `BE0112412` and when I calculate it , it gives me 4 as result but in mrz check digit is 8 . And this mrz is real mrz so 8 must be correct. Why this is not working for this MRZ even it works for anothers I tried?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your case and it gave `8` when you have letter **O** and it gave `4` when you have number **0**.

Here is complete python code `checkdigit.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys 

def getcharvalue(c):
    if c >= '0' and c <= '9':
        return ord(c) - ord('0')
    if c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z':
        return ord(c) - ord('A') + 10
    if c == '<':
        return 0

def calc_checkdigit(data):
    multipliers = [7, 3, 1]
    s = 0
    for idx,digit in enumerate(data):
        n = getcharvalue(digit) * multipliers[idx % len(multipliers)]
        s += n
    cdigit = s % 10
    return cdigit

data = sys.argv[1]
cdigit = calc_checkdigit(data)
print(cdigit)
```

Test run:

```
./checkdigit.py "BEO112412" # this prints 8
./checkdigit.py "BE0112412" # this prints 4
```